# Customize build directory in 'npm start' command

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, npm-install, npm-start

I have Angular app built with npm and web-pack served on Tomcat web server.

Command `npm run build` builds all JS files into `/build` directory of the project, but `npm start` uses `/out` directory.

Is there any way to force `npm start` using `/build` directory as well?

***Why I need this:***
Currently JS content is served together with backend written with Java and there is no difference between production run and dev run (both use the same build folder). It would also be convenient to have the same on frontend side.

**UPDATE: I've solved the problem by enhancing webpack config**

`npm start` runs webpack under the hood which is configured via `.js` script.

I have updated section:

```
output: {
    path: helpers.root('../build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
}
```

pointing to the `./build` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) for this, in your `packages.json` use something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "client": "cd build && npm start",
  "server": "cd out && npm start",
  "start": "concurrent \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\"",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^3.5.0"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've solved the problem by configuring webpack. Find my update in the question.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota you should post that separately as an answer.